# MyBatis-Spring setup not using transactions

Tags: spring, transactions, ibatis, mybatis, spring-transactions

I have a web application set up with MyBatis and Spring, but it doesn't seem to be using any transactions. Here's the configuration:

applicationContext.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- <tx:jta-transaction-manager /> --> <!-- using WebSphere 7 -->

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/my_datasource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="testDAO" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.lmig.TestDAO" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Sample bean method with transaction definition:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void testDelete() {
    testDAO.firstDelete(); //always successful
    testDAO.secondDelete(); //always throws SQLServerException
}
```

TestDAO:

```
public interface TestDAO {
    public void firstDelete();
    public void secondDelete();
}
```

Server debug log:

```
[11/17/11 16:42:07:998 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Creating SqlSession with JDBC Connection [com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@34ba34ba] 
[11/17/11 16:42:07:999 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [java.sql.Connection] ooo Connection Opened 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:001 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction] JDBC Connection [com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@34ba34ba] will be managed by Spring 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:005 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@74247424] 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:025 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement] ==>  Executing: delete from test1  
[11/17/11 16:42:08:025 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement] ==> Parameters:  
[11/17/11 16:42:08:097 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@74247424] 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:099 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Transaction synchronization committing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@74247424] 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:123 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@74247424] 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:136 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Creating SqlSession with JDBC Connection [com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@17351735] 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:137 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [java.sql.Connection] ooo Connection Opened 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:138 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction] JDBC Connection [com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@17351735] will be managed by Spring 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:139 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d871d87] 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:145 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement] ==>  Executing: delete from test2  
[11/17/11 16:42:08:146 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement] ==> Parameters:
[11/17/11 16:42:08:490 PST] 0000002b XmlBeanDefini I org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
[11/17/11 16:42:08:554 PST] 0000002b SQLErrorCodes I org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory <init> SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
[11/17/11 16:42:08:560 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d871d87] 
[11/17/11 16:42:08:597 PST] 0000002b SystemOut     O DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d871d87]
...SQLServerException follows...
```

Since `secondDelete()` throws an exception, the entire transaction would be expected to roll back. However, this isn't the case, and the `firstDelete()` is still committed. I've tried all combinations of the transaction manager config (Spring-managed, app server-managed, both) but I keep getting the same results. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Mybatis 3, Spring 3 on WebSphere 7 with SQL Server 2005 as the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out: my `testDelete()` method wasn't a Spring-managed bean, so it wasn't participating in Spring-managed transactions. I changed my configuration to this, and now it's working.

Comment: This was the solution that helped me. Specifically, the annotated method was not _inside_ a spring-managed component, namely a @Service